# Map nested interfaces to a single type with the path as key while preserving the type

Tags: typescript

Typescript 4.1 introduced [template-literal-types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#template-literal-types) which now allow us to map strings. Take the following interfaces as example:

```typescript
interface User {
    id: number;
    userName: string;
    age: number;
}

interface Post {
    id: number;
    author: User;
    subject: string;
    body: string;
}

interface Queue {
   id: number;
   size: number;
   posts: Post[];
}
```

what I now want to do is mapping the `Queue` to a type with the property-path as key and the value as type like so:

```
// I want to do this:
type Properties = MapProperties<Queue>;

// ... to get the same result as this:
type Properties = {
    'id': number;                    // Queue > id
    'size': number;                  // Queue > size
    'posts.id': number;              // Queue > Post > id
    'posts.author.id': number;       // Queue > Post > User > id
    'posts.author.userName': string; // Queue > Post > User > userName
    'posts.author.age': number;      // Queue > Post > User > age
    'posts.subject': string;         // Queue > Post > subject
    'posts.body': string;            // Queue > Post > body
};
```

What I've managed so far is extracting the whole set of keys. Just mapping them to the type seems impossible to me:

```typescript
// Removing the `keyof` won't work...
type MapProperties<T> = keyof {
    [
        K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? `${K & string}.${MapProperties<T[K]> & string}` :
            T extends Array<infer U> ? MapProperties<U> : K
    ]?: T[K]
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I also want to make it recursive so that it's not limited to a certain depth (excluding circular references).

Comment: I don’t get the logic behind `posts.id`; isn’t `posts` an array?  It doesn’t have an `id` property; it has numeric indices.

Comment: @jcalz I'm resolving the arrays item-type with `T extends Array<infer U> ...`. `U` will be the type of what we have an array from :)

Comment: Translating the code from the other question here yields [this](https://tsplay.dev/Qmb8Bw).